# Woocommerce Sub Category Template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I have decided I wanted 2 different templates for my Woocommerce shop.

I found a nice little chunk that basically told me to edit taxonomy-product_cat.php

All of my shop pages are category/archive pages. And My Parent Categories have about 50 Sub Cats a piece.

So My code is as follows in taxonomy-product_cat.php :

```
if (is_product_category( 'outdoor-furniture' ) ){ wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
}
else { wc_get_template( 'archive-product-list.php' );
}
```

The problem is that archive-product.php is only being applied to the "outdoor-furniture" category and none of its subcategories.

I understand I could list || is_product_category( 'another-cat' ) but to do it for 50 is ridiculous.

I have tried several things for several hours. Stuff that involved filters to the functions file. If statements for this taxonomy-product_cat file. I cant seem to get anything working.

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Just testing your code:

```
if (is_product_category( 'books' ) || is_product_category( 'magazines' ) ):
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
else: 
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product-list.php' );
    echo 'Hellllllooooo world';
endif;
```

Actually worked for me in switching the `Woocommerce` templates depending on the product category in view.

Comment: @thewaywewere Haven't logged in for a while. Excellent news to see this ended up helping someone!

Answer (score 0):

High All,

I found a working solution:

```
if ( has_term( 'outdoor-furniture', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
}
else { wc_get_template( 'archive-product-list.php' );
}
```

Thanks for anyone who viewd. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Cheers